# UIScrollView SetZoomScale not work

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, zooming

after read some other cuestions about it i've tried:
on ViewController.m

DelegateScrollView ScrollView;

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    ScrollView = [[DelegateScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,-   self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    ScrollView.delegate = ScrollView;
    ScrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    ScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor ];
    ScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 5.0f;
    ScrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0f;
    [self.view addSubview:ScrollView];
    [ScrollView setZoomScale:2 animated:YES];

     }
```

DelegateScrollView.h:

```
@interface ChildDelegateScrollView : UIScrollView <UIScrollViewDelegate>

@end
```

and zoom never happends also i've tried this in ViewController.h: `@interface ViewController : UIViewController  <UIScrollViewDelegate>`  then set delegate like this `ScrollView.delegate = self;` and not work, how is the way to set correctly a delegate to a ScrollView?

Comment: Why do you have a childdelegate scrollView? You have a scrollview that is a inherits the UIscrollview and then you are setting that as the delegate. What are you trying to do there?

Comment: i really dont know why, that is just a solution for this problem that somebody found on another cuestion, setting itself as delegate since it has `<UIScrollViewDelegate>`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This line from the [UIScrollView class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html%20%22UIScrollView%20reference) seems to be relevant:

> For zooming and panning to work, the delegate must implement both viewForZoomingInScrollView: and scrollViewDidEndZooming:withView:atScale:

I was able to get a UILabel on a UIScrollView to zoom using this UIViewController code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () <UIScrollViewDelegate> {
    UIScrollView *_scrollView;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    scrollView.delegate = self;
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 5.0f;
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0f;
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height);
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
    _scrollView = scrollView;

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50.0, 50.0, 100.0, 25.0)];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    label.text = @"Test";
    [_scrollView addSubview:label];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [_scrollView setZoomScale:4.0 animated:YES];
}

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return _scrollView.subviews.firstObject;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(CGFloat)scale
{

} 

@end
```